# Помогите написать PHP для интерактивного калькулятора с использование рафаэля

Tags: php, калькулятор

Есть очень классный калькулятор расчета грузоподъемности автокрана с использованием библиотеки raphael.

Вот ссылка на рабочий пример: https://www.hydroservice-spb.ru/calculator/

Хочу сделать такой же.

Почти получилось - стрела крана двигается, значения считываются,

НО! осталось написать **php-файл** который выполняет функцию фильтрации по заданным параметрам - в примере в файле js идет обращение к php-файлу где собственно и происходит вся магия.

Ссылка на JS-скрипт:
https://www.hydroservice-spb.ru/wp-content/themes/engines/assets/js/podbor.js

Вот его фрагмент (в самом конце файла podbor.js)

```
jQuery(function($){
$('#buttonPodbor2').click(function(){
    var visota = $('input[name="visota"]').val();
    var ydalenie = $('input[name="ydalenie"]').val();
    var vesGruza = $('input[name="vesGruza"]').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/ajax/filter.php",
        data: {visota:visota, ydalenie:ydalenie,vesGruza:vesGruza}
    })
    .done(function( result ){
            $("#ListAvtokran2").html(result);
            $('#buttonPodbor2').text('Подобрать кран');
    });
});
});
```

В php не силен, может кто подскажет, что должно быть в файле filter.php?

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего в файле /ajax/filter.php (куда идет ajax запрос и отправляются данные, выбранные пользователем) происходит выборка из базы данных по параметрам, которые пришли в массив $_POST от клиента. Потом, возможно, в цикле (если в выборке есть результаты) создается HTML, который и возвращается и далее это HTML вставляется в блок с id="ListAvtokran2".

Comment: Да, это логично.
Был бы очень признателен если бы скинули примерный черновик как делать эту самую выборку из БД по параметрам, пришедшим из массива $_POST

Answer (score 0):

Если на чистом SQL (без применения PDO, DAO)

```
    SELECT krani.name, krani.img, krani.param1 FROM krani WHERE krani.visota {{условие}}, krani.ydalenie  {{условие}}, krani.vesGruza  {{условие}};
```

На а какие именно будут {{условия}} это определяется задачей и типами данных, которые хранятся в таблице 'krani'